# Sequence' requires the types 'ZBarSymbolSet.Element' (aka 'ZBarSymbol') and 'Any' be equivalent

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

This code works fine with Swift 3 but fails with an error with Swift 4:

> 'Sequence' requires the types 'ZBarSymbolSet.Element' (aka 'ZBarSymbol') and 'Any' be equivalent

```
extension ZBarSymbolSet: Sequence
{
    public typealias Element  = ZBarSymbol
    public typealias Iterator = NSFastEnumerationIterator

    public func makeIterator() -> NSFastEnumerationIterator
    {
        return NSFastEnumerationIterator(self)
    }
}
```

...

```
if (self.ZBarReader == nil) {
    self.ZBarReader = ZBarReaderViewController()
}
self.ZBarReader?.readerDelegate = self
self.ZBarReader?.scanner.setSymbology(ZBAR_UPCA, config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE, to: 1)
self.ZBarReader?.readerView.zoom = 1.0
self.ZBarReader?.isModalInPopover = false
self.ZBarReader?.showsZBarControls = false
navigationController?.pushViewController(self.ZBarReader!, animated:true)
```

...

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    guard let symbols = info[ZBarReaderControllerResults] as? ZBarSymbolSet else { return }

    for symbol in symbols
    {
         if let symbol = symbol as? ZBarSymbol, let data = symbol.data
         {
            print(data)
         }
     }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?